# Can't get the changed global variable

Tags: python

t.py

```
value = 0

def change_value():
    global value
    value = 10
```

s.py

```
import t
from t import value

t.change_value()

print(f'test1: {t.value}')
print (f'test2: {value}')
```

Output

> test1: 10
>
> test2: 0

Why isn't it not returning the changed value in the test2 ?

Comment: @Ouroborus: No, that's not true, look at test1, it is propagating. It's because of the `from import`, I guess, it looks like that copies by value instead of by reference.

Comment: I guess `from t import value` is pretty much the same as `value = t.value`, and changing `t.value` won't change `value` then, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how `import` works in Python. You should read what the documentation says on [the `import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) carefully.

Specifically, when you use the `from import` syntax on a module attribute, Python looks up the value of that attribute, and then "a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace".

So, if `value` is `10`, then after `from t import value` you have a reference to `10`.  That `10` stays a `10` no matter what happens to `t.value`.

Just to drive home the point about reference semantics vs. value semantics, consider what would happen if you had this in `t.py` instead:

```
value = []

def change_value():
    global value # not actually needed anymore
    value.append(10)

def change_reference():
    global value
    value = value + [10]
```

Contrast the differences between calling `t.change_value()` and `t.change_reference()`. In the first case, both prints would be the same, while in the second, they would be different.

This is because after calling `change_value()` we only have one list, and the name `value` in `s.py` is referring to it. With `change_reference()` we have two lists, the original (empty) one and a new one, and `value` in `s.py` is still referring to the original one.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main point of confusion is that with `from t import value` you are not importing a complex module or another reference to a mutable object, but a simple immutable `int` (in this case). In a way, `from t import value` is about the same as `value = t.value` (assuming you already imported `t` before), storing the value of `t.value` in another variable (also called `value`). Assigning a new value to `t.value` won't change the value assigned to `value`.

Comment: How can i import the reference to `value` then

Comment: @ABHIJITHEA You can't, really, since the value of `value` is an immutable `int`. The only way to keep a reference to `value` in `t` is by using `t.value`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're importing `value` before updating it. Here's what your code does:

1. Imports the `t.py` and then `t.value`
2. Runs the `t.change_value()` function which makes `value = 10`.
3. Prints `t.value` and `value`.

Now note, your `value` is already imported in the start which was 0. Therefore, if you want `value` to be equal to `t.value`, then you need to import it after updating. Yes, it's a headache but this is how Python works.

Updated Code:

```
import t
t.change_value()
from t import value
print(f'test1: {t.value}')
print (f'test2: {value}')
```

Output:

```
test1: 10
test2: 10
```

However, if you don't want to import later on. You can make `change_value()` return `value` and update it as well, so that it's accessible in `t.py` and `s.py` simultaneously.

Recommend Code:

```
import t
from t import value
value = t.change_value()
print(f'test1: {t.value}')
print (f'test2: {value}')
```

*Both give the same output*

Comment: I'm not sure your answer really clarifies the underlying question of why `t.value` and `value` are 2 different objects.

Comment: Well, I did state that they imported `value` before updating it. And when we import specific variables from a file, it simply isn't a reference.

Comment: @TheMyth That's simply incorrect

Comment: Oh, then please elaborate on your opinion as to why this is happening. I find no reason.

Comment: @TheMyth will do

Comment: @TheMyth thanks for the answer it gives me the  expected out but I would like to know like @matszwecja said why `t.value` and `value` are different

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

t.py

```
value = [1000]

def change_value():
    global value
    value[0] = 1001
```

s.py

```
import t as t
from t import value
t.change_value()
print(f'test1: {t.value[0]}')
print (f'test2: {value[0]}')
```

Output:

```
test1: 1001
test2: 1001
```

Ok, so what is going on?
Integers are **immutable**, which means when defined, it is no longer possible to change what value given object represents. When you reassign an integer, you are really creating a new `int` object and changing the reference to point to this new object.

Which leads us to observed behaviour: `t.value` and `value` are 2 separate variables - initially, they point to the same address. But when we change one of them, Python cannot change the actual value so it changes the reference. And because reference is bound to a variable, it changes for only one of them.

Using mutable types like int lets us change its content without changing the reference, so both variables still point to the same object and changes are visible for both.

Comment: This isn't about integers being interned, it's about them being **immutable**. You got the behavior you got because you imported after the function call. This same behavior would appear with smaller integers or tuples.

Comment: @cha0site aye, my bad, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have someone's number saved in your phone.

```
### In your phone:
Alice:  312 3456789
Bob:    614 7984321
```

Your friend Carol has some other numbers in her phone.

```
### In Carol's phone
Dave:   602 9406981
Erin:   216 3714732
```

After the dinner party, Carol asks you for Alice's phone number, and you share it with her. Now:

```
### In your phone:
Alice:  312 3456789
Bob:    614 7984321

### In Carol's phone
Dave:   602 9406981
Alice:  312 3456789
Erin:   216 3714732
```

At some later date, Alice tells you "*Hey, I'm changing phone numbers, here's the new number*" so you update your phone:

```
### In your phone:
Alice:  312 1111111  <--- Alice's new number
Bob:    614 7984321

### In Carol's phone
Dave:   602 9406981
Alice:  312 3456789
Erin:   216 3714732
```

This *doesn't* magically update Carol's phone, so she's still got the old number. You can't actually edit a *number*, it's immutable, the thing you updated here is a phone directory - a mapping of names to numbers.

Modules in Python are analogous to this situation. Module `t` has a *namespace*, `t.__dict__` mapping names to values. Module `s` also has a namespace `s.__dict__`.  The function `t.change_value` only updates an entry for the name "value" in its own "phone directory" i.e. in `t.__dict__`. There is no mechanism for that action to update other unrelated namespaces at the same time.